# Not able to see CPT archive template

Tags: custom-post-type-archives, archive-template

I am not sure what I am missing here , the cpt archive page simply does not want to show. I reset permalinks ( currenlty on default )  , copied `archive.php` and renamed to `archive-articles.php` ( tested anything I could think of ) but the **custom template** does not want to show. It loads **default archive.ph**p. Testing on twentyseventeen. The `single-article.php` worked out of the box but not the archive.

```
/****************************************
 * Add custom taxonomy for Articles *
 ****************************************/

add_action('init', 'articles_categories_register');

function articles_categories_register() {
$labels = array(
    'name'                          => 'Articles Categories',
    'singular_name'                 => 'Articles Category',
    'search_items'                  => 'Search Articles Categories',
    'popular_items'                 => 'Popular Articles Categories',
    'all_items'                     => 'All Articles Categories',
    'parent_item'                   => 'Parent Article Category',
    'edit_item'                     => 'Edit Article Category',
    'update_item'                   => 'Update Article Category',
    'add_new_item'                  => 'Add New Article Category',
    'new_item_name'                 => 'New Article Category',
    'separate_items_with_commas'    => 'Separate articles categories with commas',
    'add_or_remove_items'           => 'Add or remove articles categories',
    'choose_from_most_used'         => 'Choose from most used articles categories'
    );

$args = array(
    'label'                         => 'Articles Categories',
    'labels'                        => $labels,
    'public'                        => true,
    'hierarchical'                  => true,
    'show_ui'                       => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'             => true,
    'args'                          => array( 'orderby' => 'term_order' ),
    'rewrite'                       => array( 'slug' => 'articles', 'with_front' => true, 'hierarchical' => true ),
    'query_var'                     => true
);

register_taxonomy( 'articles_categories', 'articles', $args );
}

/*****************************************
 * Add custom post type for Articles *
 *****************************************/

add_action('init', 'articles_register');

function articles_register() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Articles',
        'singular_name' => 'Article',
        'add_new' => 'Add New',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Article',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Article',
        'new_item' => 'New Article',
        'view_item' => 'View Article',
        'search_items' => 'Search Articles',
        'not_found' =>  'Nothing found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'Nothing found in Trash',
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'articles', 'with_front' => true ),
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'menu_position' => 6,
        'supports' => array('title', 'excerpt', 'editor','thumbnail') //here you can specify what type of inputs will be accessible in the admin area
      );

    register_post_type( 'articles' , $args );
}
```

Comment: can you clear something up?  You say that the single is working but not the archive.  Your code shows the CPT is "articles" but by that name, single should NOT be working and the archive should... I usually pluralize everything.  Also i would add a namespace identifier.  ie change the register cpt to 'benn_articles' or something and then both archive-benn_articles.php and single-benn_articles.php.  Make sure to flush permalinks after you do this.

Comment: If you are on localhost then try to rename the file again write all the text yourself. There is some bug in win10 when I copy files I can delete the "- copy" and have the same name a without limits... and the file archive-articles.php not loading to me too until I renamed it and write all his name manually.

Comment: @rudtek tried everything , flushing, renaming , underscores , nothing worked .

Comment: I'll test on my end.  Give me a few

Comment: @Shibi  yes localhost , and just tried your suggestion, same thing

Comment: Your code working for me so I don't know why its doesn't for you. maybe you have a page or post with the same slug and its doing some conflicts with the archive template..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I set my system up with the exact same as your code above.  I get the same results.  What I did to fix it was change your line

```
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'articles', 'with_front' => true ),
```

to

```
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'articles2', 'with_front' => true ),
```

and then to

```
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'articlis', 'with_front' => true ),
```

and everything loaded fine on the last 2 options.  It looks like maybe there is perhaps a built-in usage of articles already so that when you re-write to "articles" wordpress isn't sure what to do. I don't have an explanation for it.

What I would suggest all the same is use a CPT name more specific than what you are currently using.

Instead of articles, can you use a name that is actually what the post will represent?  Changing

Comment: what I just found is that is actually custom tax so is looking for,  taxonomy-articles_categories,  I would prefer archive-articles.php   rather .   Yes I can change it to anything , actually just testing the CPT

Comment: try changing like above.  Make sure to flush permalinks between. I think you'll see it works.

Comment: could you mark the answer?

Comment: this did not work for me . Here try this complete CPT please http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/253995/cpt-tax-slug-conflict-with-post-type-slug    taxonomy-docs-category works but not archive-docs-category or archive-anything

Comment: That appears to be a different issue.  I'll look at it though.  I double checked again with the code above it solves your issue though.  Can you please double check (including flushing permalinks?)