# CPT tax slug conflict with post type slug

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I am working on documentation CPT and need following permalinks structure

```
site/documentation - > documentation archive 
site/documentation/product-name - > product tax
site/documentation/product-name/basics - > product sub tax
site/documentation/product-name/basics/installation - > sub tax item single
```

issue is that I need to use same slug for tax and post_type in order to get the above links , but than the slugs conflict and no matter what combo I get I either end-up with 404 on sub tax item or on sub tax. 
I have been searching for solution but no slug combo or filters can get me the desired result.

Here is complete CPT

```
// Register Custom taxonomy
add_action('init', 'docs_tax_register');

function docs_tax_register() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                          => _x( 'Docs Categories','taxonomy general name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'                 => _x( 'Docs Category','taxonomy singular name', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'                  => __( 'Search Docs Categories', 'text_domain' ),
        'popular_items'                 => __( 'Popular Docs Categories', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'                     => __( 'All Docs Categories', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item'                   => __( 'Parent Docs Category', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'                     => __( 'Edit Docs Category', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'                   => __( 'Update Docs Category', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'                  => __( 'Add New Docs Category', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item_name'                 => __( 'New Docs Category', 'text_domain' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas'    => __( 'Separate docs categories with commas', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_or_remove_items'           => __( 'Add or remove docs categories', 'text_domain' ),
        'choose_from_most_used'         => __( 'Choose from most used docs categories', 'text_domain' )
    );

    $rewrite = array( 
        'slug' => 'documentation', 
        'hierarchical' => true, 
        'with_front' => false 
    );

    $args = array(
        'label'                         => __('Docs Categories', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'                        => $labels,
        'public'                        => true,
        'hierarchical'                  => true,
        'show_ui'                       => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'             => true,
        'args'                          => array( 'orderby' => 'term_order' ),
        'rewrite'                       => $rewrite,
        'query_var'                     => true
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'docs-category', 'docs-items', $args );
}


// Register Custom Post Type
function docs_items_post_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Documentation', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Article', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Documentation', 'text_domain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Article', 'text_domain' ),
        'archives'              => __( 'Item Archives', 'text_domain' ),
        'attributes'            => __( 'Item Attributes', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_items'            => __( 'View Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
        'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'text_domain' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into item', 'text_domain' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this item', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list'            => __( 'Items list', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter items list', 'text_domain' ),
    );

    $rewrite = array(
        'slug' => 'documentation/%docs-category%', 
        'with_front' => true
    );

    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'Article', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Site articles.', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt','thumbnail', 'revisions', ),
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'docs-category'),
        'hierarchical'          => true,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => 'docs-category',     
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'post',
        'rewrite'               => $rewrite

    );
    register_post_type( 'docs-items', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'docs_items_post_type', 0 );




function docs_items_links( $post_link, $id = 0 ){
    $post = get_post($id);  
    if ( is_object( $post ) ){
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'docs-category' );
         if( $terms ){

            $term_slug = $terms[0]->slug;

            if($terms[0]->parent){
                $category_parent = get_term($terms[0]->parent, 'docs-category' );
                $parent_slug    = $category_parent->slug;
                // site/tax/sub-tax/item works only with comma not with forward slash
                // so it ends up being site/tax,sub-tax/item
                $term_slug      = $parent_slug.'/'.$terms[0]->slug; 
            }
            return str_replace( '%docs-category%' , $term_slug, $post_link );
        }
    }
    return $post_link;  
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'docs_items_links', 1, 3 );
```

any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you're trying with specifics so I can better understand your goal?  Why do they have to be the same?

Comment: @rudtek I am after this type of docs links hierarchy https://yjsimplegrid.com/documentation

Comment: When i look at that page i see that it's loading /CPT/CPTCAT/CPTPOST.  So there is only which is the normal method.  Where are you seeing that you need to have the same slug for tax and post type.  I would if you need cat and sub cats can you make them parent-child in the CPT category section.  that will load it properly in your file structure above.